# Realm записывает только последнее значение массива

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, realm

Добрый день. Начал разбираться с Realm и столкнулся с элементарной проблемой, а именно: у меня есть большой массив, который я получаю из вне, а потом данные кладу в БД. Но проблема в том, что в БД заносится только последний элемент массива. В чем может быть проблема?

Модель:

```
class News: Object {

  @objc dynamic var source: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var link: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var author: String = ""

}
```

Функция, которая получает и заносит данные в БД:

```
func getNews(_ feedItem: [MWFeedItem]) {

    arrayNews = feedItem
    print(arrayNews.count) // до занесения в БД, массив заполнен
    let realm = try! Realm()
      try! realm.write {
          for new in self.arrayNews{
            self.news.author = "new.author"
            self.news.date = "new.date"
            self.news.link = new.link
            self.news.source = (self.source?.nameOfSource)!
            self.news.title = new.title
            realm.add(self.news)
            }
          }
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!! В БД:\(realm.objects(News.self).count)")
    print(realm.objects(News.self))

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откуда у вас переменная self.news?

Вы должны создавать новую переменную в каждой итерации цикла, что то типа:

```
var new_item = News()
```